# Study interrelationships between the variables in the dataset

Tags: r

What is the best way to determine the inter relationships among the variables in a dataset. Assume that I have dataset as below.

```
a  b  c  d  e
1  1  1  1  1
3  4  7  2  3
4  5  7  8  1
```

I would want to study the following

- a is influenced by c+d
- e is influenced by a+b+c+d

I want to study their interrelationships assuming there are 30+ variables.Along a mix of continuous and categorical variables.

Comment: One quick way to investigate this would be to build a random forest model using `a` as the response variable and `c`, `d` as the predictors.  There are really many ways you could try to model this data.  If you give us more details maybe we can give a more focused answer.

Comment: Too broad as there are many possible answers to this...

Comment: This is a much too general question, and not really about programming in R. But anyways: maybe start with some correlation plots (assuming linear dependence)...

Answer (score 0):

In R, I would use the following methods:

1. correlation plots (corrplot via [corrplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html))
2. interaction plots (interaction.plot via [stats](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/interaction.plot.html))
3. PCA (PCA via [FactoMiner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/FactoMineR.pdf))
4. hierarchical clustering (hclustvar via [ClustOfVar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustOfVar/ClustOfVar.pdf))

3 and 4 aren't primary intended to examine interaction but can still provide useful insights into potential interrelationships.